# Размер шрифта TextView по размеру экрана

Tags: java, android, textview

Есть текст. Уже с разметкой.
 Задача: отобразить его в TextView в соответствии с разметкой, без дополнительных переносов.
 Идея: сделать это за счёт подбора размера шрифта перед отображением на дисплее. Реализация: 
Устанавливаем шрифт

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,mTextSize(TEXT));
```

---

Измеряем некую TextView с текстом, который хотим отобразить. Размер шрифта произвольный. TextView не имеет ограничений и должна принять размеры в зависимости от текста( а может и нет?). Также измеряем дисплей и по пропорции вычисляем необходимый нам размер шрифта. Такой, чтобы текст отобразился на нашем экране без ограничений и лишних переносов.

```
private float mTextSize(String mText){
        TextView mTextView = new TextView(this);
        mTextView.setText(mText);
        mTextView.setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,111);
        mTextView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int mWidth = mTextView.getMeasuredWidth();
        float textSize = (getDisplayWidth()*111)/mWidth;            
        return  textSize;

    }
```

---

Метод. Ширина дисплея устройства

```
private int getDisplayWidth (){
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point point = new Point();
    display.getSize(point);
    int width = point.x;
    return width;
}
```

В итоге рассчитывается размер шрифта. Но такой, как будто этого и не происходило. Т.е. размер рассчитывается ровно такой, какой он по умолчанию без расчётов определяется TextView. Соответственно текст отображается с лишними переносами. Мне же надо, что бы какой бы длинной не была самая длинная строка, она должна влезть в экран целиком, пусть даже шрифт будет минимальным.
 Думаю что проблема связана с тем, что TextView при создании получает context, поэтому не является оторванной от устройства. Как можно это исправить?Что не так в моём подходе? Какими подходами пользуйтесь вы?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Comment: @pavlofff добавил `TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(mTextView,TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM); в метод mTextSize().`Считает верно. Есть ли способы обойтись стандартными инструментами без написания методов?

Comment: библиотеки поддержки - стандартные инструменты разработки. о каких написаниях методов вы говорите?

Comment: @pavlofff Я говорю, без методов mTextSize и getDispayWidth.

Comment: Что значит "текст с разметкой"? Можете привести пример такой строки в вопросе (добавить в вопрос)?

Answer (score 1):

В support-библиотеке андроида есть готовое решение для этого. Просто нужно использовать AppCompatTextView с необходимыми атрибутами:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

Во-первых, для включения функции нужно указать атрибут autoSizeTextType, а также задать минимальный и максимальный размер шрифта. Если хотите запретить переносы, то укажите maxLines=1.

Обратите внимание, что используется AppCompatTextView, а не просто TextView.

Кроме того, проверьте, что у вас в build.gradle есть зависимость на com.android.support:appcompat-v7.

Больше примеров в гайде [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

Comment: Текст многострочный при  maxLines = 1  отображается только первая строка. Попробовал разные варианты, в том числе подсчитывать и выставлять количество строк. Но без метода подсчёта размера шрифта это не работает.

Comment: Можете ли посчитать, сколько переносов в вашей строке? Есть такой вариант: выставить maxLines равным количеству переносов в вашей строке + 1. Кроме того, чтобы избавиться от дополнительных переносов,  заменить все пробелы в тексте на неразрывные пробелы: `textView.setText(text.replace(' ', '\u00A0'))`.

Comment: Да. Так работает. Не нужны никакие расчёты. CompatTextView с uniform. масштабируют текст по ширине и высоте экрана. Проблема в том, что мне нужно только по ширине. Но uniform используется только с match_parent. Видимо придётся вернуться к старым методам.